# How do I define the carousel size in Bootstrap 3.3.6

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m trying to adapt the carousel in Bootstrap 3.3.6 to a fixed height and a width of 100%. Do anyone know which css section I have to alter? Or should I define my own one? I´ve searched so long on the internet but nothing helped me.

I tried it with this code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="~/images/Digitale-Vernetzung.jpg" alt="ASP.NET" class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <p>
```

CSS:

```
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  height:500px;


}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;

}
.carousel-inner > .item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
       -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
          transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  line-height: 1;
}
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition:      -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
            transition:         transform .6s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.carousel-control.right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-family: serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
  content: '\2039';
}
.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
  content: '\203a';
}
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000 \9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
.carousel-caption .btn {
  text-shadow: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
  .carousel-control .icon-prev,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
  .carousel-control .icon-prev {
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    margin-right: -10px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    right: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

But when I used it nothing happend. Could someone please help me?

Best Regards,

CD Rohling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried applying the height to the container element and then telling the inner carousel (the part containing the slides) to be 100% height of it's parent?

Something like:

```css
.carousel {
    height: 300px;
}
.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators"> ... </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active"> ... </div>
    <div class="item active"> ... </div>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: This adapted the height but not the width. Thats what I tried:

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  height:500px;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;

Comment: When you say, _"...but not the width." The width of what? The `.carousel-inner` element should be a 100% the width of it's parent element. I'm assuming it's the images themselves that are not adjusting? Versus `.carousel-inner` or `.item` elements.

Comment: I´m meaning the width of the whole carousel. The both arrows should be at the right and left border and if i adapt the screen size the carousel should also adapt its size.

Comment: The carousel [resizes (adjusts to screen size) by default](https://jsfiddle.net/aa9h12hu/). Not sure what you're getting at. You must have some other CSS interfering or you're not communicating enough information. You really should include your code in your post.

Comment: One more thing: At a size it always sticks to the borders. The only thing what i want is that it always stick at them. I´ve added the Code of bootstrap. hopefully this is the right one.